# Netflix archaius 2 manual

Tags: java, netflix-archaius

Does anyone know how to initialise Netflix archaius version 2?

In version 1, you can pass a system property to setup the configuration source:

```
-Darchaius.configurationSource.additionalUrls=file:///apps/myapp/application.properties
```

However, no such property seems to exist for version 2. The wiki only appears to document earlier versions. The README for the V2 branch contains a few details, but it's not nearly as comprehensive as the project wiki (which is still aimed at V1)

Comment: There seems to be no wiki for version 2 yet, try switching to 2.x branch and refer to the Readme file and indicated test case classes, https://github.com/Netflix/archaius/tree/2.x

Comment: I forgot to mention that I'd read the README on the branch, and it does help a little, but only enough to get going. The test samples are pretty basic too.